git merge conflict resolution when both renamed and modified
For example there was a file in a project named "foo". On the main branch it was renamed to "foo1" and the content was also modified. On another branch (lets call it 'otherbranch') it was renamed to "foo2" and its content was modified as well.
"foo" --> "foo1" --> "foo1"       < main branch
     \--> "foo2" --> "foo2"       < otherbranch branch

When we merge this branch into the main branch, we get this:
CONFLICT (rename/rename): foo renamed to foo1 in HEAD and to foo2 in otherbranch
This is really a conflict even if the contents of the files would merge without conflict because git cannot know in which filename we should put the merged content.
But for conflict resolution we want to do a real merge of the contents. But the problem is we cannot do that.
we cannot run a mergetool to really merge the two versions of the contents of this file.
We can run the mergetool on foo, or on foo1, or on foo2 but in any case we can just select which file to keep and which file to delete.
However from the conflict message of git we see that git obviously knows that these three files are the different versions of the SAME file. So git would be (and should be) able to give these three versions of the file to the 3-way merging merge tool. We should specify the file for example by the name of the file in the version in the HEAD (because this is the 'local' branch in our merge now):
git mergetool foo1
This command should understand that for the 3-way merging the local version is "foo1" from the HEAD, the 3-way base of the merging is the file "foo" from the base commit, and the 3-way remote version is "foo2" from 'otherbranch'.
This is a simple logic operation, git knows everything to do it but it does not do.
How can we do this with git?
Of course with different tricks and using 'git show' I can manually get the base file "foo", the other branch's file "foo2", and the foo1 of HEAD and I can run kdiff3 on these files but the problem is that I have many similar files in one project and this tedious work should be totally automatic by the git.
Can I run this 3-way merge somehow with a simple command?
UPDATE
(This was too long for writing it in comment)
One problem is that foo was only a one file example but I have many foos in the project.
Other circumstances: in the main branch I had to rename/move all java files because I converted the project from ant based to gradle based and the file structure was different. Than I've made other further development on this branch and so some files were further renamed/moved. Meanwhile the old 'otherbranch' was still the production line. Than I was forced to do some development on the production line (still ant based). So now I want to merge the production line into the gradle based main line (and it is intended to replace the production line later).
And since yesterday I experienced that I've made a small mistake. I thought that if I made a move of the .java file from src/java to src/main/java (to be same as in gradle version), it would be better for merging. But it's acutally quite the opposite. Because in this way the otherbranch also had a rename. It is better to leave the production branch as it was and do the merge and there are much less (rename/rename) conflict.

Renaming the same file two different ways was clearly a mistake, so why not just make a commit that renames foo2 to foo1 and now merge the branches?

Not everyone renames a template to two different other files on separate branches with the intent of merging them back together. If the files were named sample.config at the base, server.config on the master and client.config on the other branch, you could equally vehemently argue Git should somehow divine that those two files shouldn't be merged.
Tell Git what you want for a merge result here, making the index and work tree look like just one path isn't hard, it just means specifying a lot of details Git's default handling did differently:
index-combine () {
  local target=$1 tab=`printf '\t'`
  git ls-files -u "$@" \
  | awk '$2=target' target="$target" FS="$tab" OFS="$tab" \
  | git update-index --index-info
  git cat-file blob ":2:$target" >"$target"
  shift
  git rm "$@"
}

and now you can put whichever one you like first, e.g. index-combine foo foo1 foo2 with foo first to settle on foo as the right result name. With some tweaking you can preserve the initial automerge results if those look good.
git mergetool foo from there.

Actually these are not renames but moves! I just used foo, foo1, foo2, for the sake of short example but actually these are src/java/com/something/foo and src/main/java/com/somethingother/foo and src/main/java/com/something/foo.
I thought that for git logic it is totally irrelevant if just the filename is changed or the path changed.

And the names foo, foo1, foo2 (which are actually long different pathnames) are not easy to extract from the git CONFLICT information. It is tedious to get these names and do something with it. There are many-many foos in the project.
But meanwhile i realized that git actually do the merge and it just stores the same merge in merged foo1 and foo2 so I just have to select which one I want to keep. So the situation is not as worse as I believed.

Well, when you're done moving the goalposts you could look at git diff --name-status -M -C ...otherbranch and `git diff --name-status -M -C otherbranch...‘ output to get the list of renames Git detected in an easy-to-parse format. Move and rename are the same thing, the same content is at a new path.
